# Unable to add edges to a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, graphs

```
\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        C/.style = {circle, draw}, %   C: circle
        every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, pos=0.8}
        ]
        \begin{scope}[nodes={C}]
        \node (a1)   at (0,0)        {$v_2$};
        \node (a3) at (5,0)  {$v_4$};
        \node (a2) at (3,1) {$v_3$};
        \node (a0) at (2,-2)  {$v_1$};
        \node (a4) at (3,-1)  {$v_5$};
        \node (a6) at (2,2)  {$v_6$};
        \end{scope}
        %
        \path 
        (a1) edge ["\hspace{40mm} $e_{23}$"]  (a2)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{24}$"]  (a3)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{25}$"]  (a4)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{26}$"]  (a6)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{21}$"]  (a0);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Why cant I add edges between the vertices $3$ and $4$ in this tikz picture?
I dont know why when I add an edge between vertices $v_3$ and $v_4$ with a edge label $e_{34}$, the new edge does not show up and the entire graph gets disturbed.

Where am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: Try `(a1) edge node[below, pos=.75] {$e_{24}$} (a3)`. You can use `above` instead of `below` to shift the label above the edge and with `pos`, you can shift the label to the left and right (or up and down, depending on the orientation of the edge).

Comment: @JasperHabicht; its not working, can you please give a complete answer

Comment: I just got to know that there is a Ti*k*Z library for using a syntax such as yours. You need to load it first, however, in order to be able to use it. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, in order to label edges you essentially need to place a node along the path of the edge. Whithout loading any Ti*k*Z library, this can be done as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    C/.style = {circle, draw}, %   C: circle
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, pos=0.8}
    ]
    
    \begin{scope}[nodes={C}]
    \node (a1) at (0,0)  {$v_2$};
    \node (a3) at (5,0)  {$v_4$};
    \node (a2) at (3,1)  {$v_3$};
    \node (a0) at (2,-2) {$v_1$};
    \node (a4) at (3,-1) {$v_5$};
    \node (a6) at (2,2)  {$v_6$};
    \end{scope}
    
    \path 
    (a1) edge node {\hspace{40mm} $e_{23}$} (a2)
    (a1) edge node[below, pos=.75] {$e_{24}$} (a3)
    (a1) edge node[below] {$e_{25}$} (a4)
    (a1) edge node[below, xshift=5pt] {$e_{26}$} (a6)
    (a1) edge node[below, yshift=-3pt] {$e_{21}$} (a0);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can use the options `above` or `below` to place the label node above or below the edge. It is placed midways between the start and end point of the edge by default, but you can use the `pos` option to shift it (where `pos=0` means at the start point and `pos=1` at the end point). You may want to additionally shift the labels using `xshift` and `yshift`.

*However,* you probably got your code from someone who used the Ti*k*Z library `quotes`. You need to load this library in your preamble if you want to use it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes} % <-- add this!

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        C/.style = {circle, draw}, %   C: circle
        every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt, pos=0.8}
        ]
        \begin{scope}[nodes={C}]
        \node (a1)   at (0,0)        {$v_2$};
        \node (a3) at (5,0)  {$v_4$};
        \node (a2) at (3,1) {$v_3$};
        \node (a0) at (2,-2)  {$v_1$};
        \node (a4) at (3,-1)  {$v_5$};
        \node (a6) at (2,2)  {$v_6$};
        \end{scope}
        %
        \path 
        (a1) edge ["$e_{23}$"{xshift=5pt}]  (a2)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{24}$"]  (a3)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{25}$"]  (a4)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{26}$"]  (a6)
        (a1) edge ["$e_{21}$"]  (a0);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can still use the above mentioned options to shift the node. See the example fot the edge between nodes `(a1)` and `(a2)` in the above example.

[image]

Comment: Will it be possible for you to add an edge between $v_3$ and $v_4$, i dont know why but its not working in my latex document

Comment: Sure, just add `\path (a2) edge ["$x$"]  (a3);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its now working , one question, why was the command  (a2) edge ["$e_{23}$"]  (a3); not working? Any idea

Comment: It looks fine. Maybe you forgot to put `\path` before or a semicolon behind it? Every path macro in Ti*k*Z need to end with a semicolon, but within a macro, there should not be a semicolon. So, you need to be careful that you either use multiple `\path` macros for each edge, or you use just one, but then you also only should use one semicolon at the end. But this is just a guess ...